# Banana pi black screen when using hardware PWM

Tags: qt, pwm

I am using Banana Pi M1 with Lemaker 7" LCD with Touchscreen. I have qt application which uses wiringPi to contol hardware PWM (GPCLK)
Code:

```
pwm_example::pwm_example(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::pwm_example)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background: url(/root/grafix/f1_pwm_example.png);}");
    slider_value=0;
    pinMode (7, PWM_OUTPUT) ;
    pwmWrite(7, 0);
    pwmSetRange(100);
    ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(slider_value);
}
```

and i having strange behaviour. From time to time during this constructor screen becomes black. I tried to check if the same PWM pin is used to control the screen backlight but i think it's not. Also if there will be confilict with the same PWM pin for back light and for GPCLK on BPI gpios, the screen will become black every time. 
Any advices?

Comment: After this constructor wiring pi pin 7 changes from IN - LOW to ALT5 low.
Is it possible to use hardware pwm with LCD connected?